Determine scale of paper grain/tooth from scan
Drawing papers come in a defined weight (gram per square meter), but the texture of the surface isn't quantified. I'd like to create some quantitative measurement for the texture of paper that I can do at home.
Using a soft pencil (4B), I have shaded an area on the paper. Then I've scanned it. Below you find a montage of six different papers:

One can see that papers 2 and 3 are rather fine, whereas papers 4 and especially 5 are rough/coarse. We see this because the typical size of structures has a different size.
In order to formalize this, I thought about doing something like a Fourier expansion (FFT) of the image and look at the dominant frequency along both direction. The frequency mode can be converted to a wavelength in physical space (using the 600 dots/inch of the scan). Another method that I know from (one-dimensional) time series analysis would be to compute the autocorrelation between pixels to find a wavelength.
Are these sensible methods to get some numbers or are there better methods in the realm of computer vision?

Have you done a literature search on "machine vision" and "surface roughness", "surface texture", "surface finish", etc.?  Yes, the FFT or autocorrelation will work -- I suggest the discrete cosine transform as an alternative to the FFT, because it seems to be a better fit for images.

I would suggest you to try the co-occurence features GLCM.
Some example Python code can be found here:
https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_glcm.html
